# Porting XML parsing from Java to Objective C

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, porting

I am trying to port code written in Java to Objective C (for iPhone), but I'm kind of confused about a few lines of my code (mentioned below). How should I port this efficiently?

```
Namespace nmgrhistory=Namespace.getNamespace("history", "http://www.mywebsite.com/History.xsd");
        pEventEl.addContent(new Element("History",nmgrhistory));
        Namespace nmgrState=Namespace.getNamespace("state", "http://www.mywebsite.com/State.xsd");
        pEventEl.addContent(new Element("State",nmgrState));

        Iterator<Element> eld=(Iterator<Element>) pEventEl.getChild(
                pEventEl.getName() == "event"?  "./history:history/state:state" : "./state:state",pEventEl.getNamespace());
```

I'm not very sure about the replacements for the classes `Namespace`, `Iterator` and `Element`.

Anybody having idea or having done this before, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to all for making the efforts to answer, but I got a nice library [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/downloads/detail?name=TouchXML_1.0.8_Release.tar.bz2&can=1&q=) that solves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... So although these are not the actual replacements ... But basically what u need for parsing XML in Objecive - C is ["NSXMLParser"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

so u can say that NSXMLParser is the replacement for Namespace

And for "Iterator" NSXMLParserDelegate has a method named:-

```
– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
```

OR

```
– parser:foundCharacters:
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know java, but the url's your are pointing at are .xsd files which are xml definition files. XML parsing on iOS is somewhat limited out of the box: NSXMLParser.

I strongly recommend one of the bazillion open source XML parsers. They're much more user friendly.